# How do I help my kitchen window herb garden thrive?

Tags: diagnosis, containers, herbs, sunlight

For the last couple of years, I've been nursing along a sort of kitchen window herb garden consisting of cilantro, parsley, basil and chives.  What I've done is bought live herb plants at our local grocery store and re-potted them in individual pots to make it easier to move around and so on.  The window is west-facing and gets very good light in the afternoon and our kitchen is obviously warm and relatively humid.  It seemed to me an ideal location for herbs, but except for the chives have not really prospered.

But recently, aphids attacked my basil, which I moved to the front porch on the east side of the house.  After that, the aphids attacked the parsley and the cilantro, which tells me that: a) the source of the aphids is somewhere close to the kitchen window, and b) aphids prefer basil over cilantro and parsley.  The chives are growing like champions and seem to resist the aphid onslaught.

More importantly, the herbs I moved outside look better and healthier than they have in months.  In particular, the basil has suddenly burst forth in leaf and I could imagine myself harvesting some without stripping it bare.  It's a bit of a mystery to me.

Given that I'd rather have herbs growing in the kitchen where they might get used than on the porch, what could I do to improve the growing conditions inside?

---

**Update:** Based on winwead's [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/453/how-do-i-help-my-kitchen-window-herb-garden-thrive/456#456), I observed the approximate time that direct sun ended in the kitchen and yesterday it was sometime before 6pm.  Since full sun could not start before 1pm, that window has less than 5 hours of direct sun.  (It's counter-intuitive since the kitchen seems so bright all day long.  Most of that light, however, is indirect and reflected from the light stucco on the building across the alley.)  Sun starts on the porch around 8am and gets good direct light until at least 1pm, if not longer.  So that's a solid 5+ hours.

The lesson for me: it's better to measure than to guess.  Also, I need to search for herbs and plants that thrive in less direct sun for my kitchen window.

Comment: About how many hours per day of *direct* sunlight were your herbs getting in the west-facing kitchen window (and now on your east facing porch)?

Comment: @nicholas: I'm not really sure.  I do know the light can't start being direct until true noon and lasts until just about sundown.  So in the summer, that's about 5 hours if not a bit more.  On the porch, they *are* getting more sun, though various trees do shade the area from time to time.

Comment: I agree with @winwaed.  It's probably the additional sunlight that's perked them up.  For some herbs and veggies, I can see a significant difference between the ones that get 7 hours and the ones that get 8.  Green pepper basil is the only variety that I grow in less than 6 hours of direct sun.

Comment: Aphids:http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/76/what-is-an-effective-organic-pesticide-to-use-against-aphids-or-cabbage-loopers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are probably getting more light outside. That Sun does wonders! Is it possible to arrange them so they get more sun in the window, or a different window?  If they grow better in the porch than the kitchen, then I think I would put them in the porch. It could be worse: You don't need to put your wellies on to go and pick some herbs!

For the aphids, they were probably on the other herbs when you moved the basil, and they weren't noticed. Once one plant has them inside, they seem to spread quickly. So I would treat the plants. Some recommend soap solutions. I use pyretheum which is effective and is meant to be safe for food and delicate plants (made from chrysanthenum extract). You still want to wash the herbs before use, of course.

Comment: They do get more light outside.  But as we are in Southern California, I figured more sun would not be of help.  As you say, there are worse problems to have than to have to go down to the porch for fresh herbs.

Comment: On the topic of aphids, is there some reason they would not be on the plants after I move them outside (knock on wood)?  I was mostly moving them to stop the spread of aphids until I determined which pesticide or deterrent to use and miraculously, they just vanished.  Maybe this would be a candidate for another question...

Comment: I saw that and was meaning to suggest a possible answer. Predators could be eating them? Lacewings, for example?

Comment: Ah.  That reminds me: I found a tiny grasshopper (or something similar) hiding on the basil when I examined it the other day.  That would explain things assuming it eats aphids.  It suggests a tactic of moving herbs indoors when I anticipate using them and taking them outside when they run into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

A second option would be to set up supplemental lighting in your kitchen.

I currently have a Aerogarden on my kitchen counter with my herbs. I use it in the winter, and switch to my outdoor garden in the summer. The Aerogarden works great, looks reasonably nice, and is easy to move to a different room if we are having company over and don't want it taking up counter space. It is also a terribly expensive option (but can be made cheaper by making your own pods, buying an adapter so you don't have to use the proprietary bulbs, etc.), so I wouldn't recommend jumping into it without checking into the costs first. It is also quite loud (I have an older model - this may not be a factor with newer ones).

A much cheaper option would be to add a grow light over your existing plants. Depending on your window, you might be able to mount the light above the spot the herbs are currently in, or under a kitchen cabinet. I'd just make sure to find a grow light that stays cool, is quiet (some have a noticeable humm that could become annoying in time), and doesn't flicker, since you'll be around it a lot in the kitchen.