# Should I pinch off flowers that form on chives?

Tags: pinching-out

I've got chives that are growing like crazy.  Recently, I noticed they are flowering, which I and my wife appreciate for the beauty.  But we also appreciate chives for their taste and [answers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/568/easy-to-grow-herbs-and-spices/587#587) to other questions indicate that pinching the flowers is advised for herbs to prevent them from maturing.  Is this true of chives as well?

By the way, I noticed in my research that the flowers of chives are [edible](http://www.ces.ncsu.edu/depts/hort/hil/hil-8110.html).  So when I get home, at least one flower will get pinched off!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always leave my chives to flower and only dead-head later - the flowers are very popular with bees!  I've never noticed any change in flavour or growth. Chives should last - and spread - for many years after planting unless they really dislike where they're planted or you have extremely severe winter freezing.

Comment: Their in a pot, love their location and are inside.  I think they'll be good.  Thanks for the suggestion and information.

Answer (score 7):

Growing like crazy is a good way to put it.  When you pinch off the plant concentrates more of its magical growing potential into the roots, and hence you have a lot more chives next year.

That being said, it certainly won't be the only reason they take over your entire garden.  I don't think chives will last very long after flowering regardless of whether you pinch them off or not though.

My son and I like to eat them too, they leave you with the raunchiest possible breath!