# How can I organically prevent green caterpillars from eating up my kale plants?

Tags: pests, organic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an effective organic pesticide to use against aphids or cabbage loopers?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/76/what-is-an-effective-organic-pesticide-to-use-against-aphids-or-cabbage-loopers)

So these little green caterpillars have been eating most of my kale plants. What can I do to prevent this from happening without chemical pesticides?

Comment: See also: [What is an effective organic pesticide to use against aphids or cabbage loopers?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/76/what-is-an-effective-organic-pesticide-to-use-against-aphids-or-cabbage-loopers)

Comment: @bstpierre @Matt these are dupes, I have closed this question.

Answer (score 4):

- Look into and read up on BTK (Bacillus Thuringiensis Kurstaki) insecticide.
- Also attracting caterpillar predators (animals, birds, etc that naturally feed on them) into your garden can make a considerable difference in their control.