# Control greenfly on strawberries

Tags: pest-control, strawberries

How can I get rid of greenfly on strawberries? I've used Rose Clear successfully on my roses but I don't really want to spray chemicals on something I want to eat.

Comment: Perhaps you are also interested in the answers on [this question about controlling greenfly on roses](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/23/99)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soap and water is an effective control or you can look at this answer [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/76/what-is-an-effective-organic-pesticide-to-use-against-aphids-or-cabbage-loopers)